# How to map a recursive object with an other recursive object in c#

Tags: c#

I have an object ObjA of type as following

```
class TypeA A
{
    string fied ID{get; set;}
    public List<TypeA> children{get; set;}
}
```

I want to copy this ObjA to ObjB which is as following

```
class TypeB B
{
    string fied ID{get; set;}
    public List<TypeB> children{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: did you take a look at AutoMapper?

Comment: Both are of a different type, so you cannot copy things here? Do you want to be able to do a cast? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Yes, I looked into the documentation of AutoMapper and unfortunately no luck there also I did find a way to map nested objects but couldn't find a solution where a field in the object if referring to list of its own type.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I meant map not to copy the object, of course, the word Copy was making a sense of copying the object so I removed that word from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy an object values from one object to another, you can have a utility function that handles the creation and assignment of one object type to another.

```
static TypeB Copy(TypeA obj)
{
    TypeB copiedObj = new TypeB();
    // Assign values from obj to copiedObj
    // copiedObj.Id = obj.Id;
    return copiedObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help you because it is unclear what you try to achieve with this.

But maybe an Interface is the best way to go for you.

```
public interface ITyp
{
    string FieldID { get; set; }

    List<ITyp> Children { get; set; }
}

public class TypA : ITyp
{
    public string FieldID { get; set; }

    public List<ITyp> Children { get; set; } = new List<ITyp>();
}

public class TypB : ITyp
{
    public string FieldID { get; set; }

    public List<ITyp> Children { get; set; } = new List<ITyp>();
}
```

With this, you can map TypA and TypB to the same object ITyp.

```
ITyp ityp = new TypA();
ityp = new TypB();
```

You can use the interface directly.

```
string ID = ityp.FieldID;
```

Or you can Convert it back to TypA or TypB.

```
TypA typaChild;
if (ityp.Children[0].GetType() == typeof(TypA)) typaChild = (TypA)ityp.Children[0];
```

Comment: Appreciate this approach but what if TypeA and TypeB aren't very similar they both have a very different type of field and while mapping we need to ignore all the field but we need to map just a few field's values only.  In this situation, this solution might fail. Can we think about a bit generic, 
ThankYou

Comment: TypA and TypB could be very different as long as they both have the properties and methods which are declared in the interface you could use that approach.